# How to save a Word template file as a .docx in VBA? Or create multiple specific documents from one excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy a bunch of text data from an excel spreadsheet into multiple separate word documents (one excel row = one document, but each column's heading has to be included before the text from the respective field of the row). I also want these documents' names to be the text from specific fields in the spreadsheet (row headers).

Because I want fancy formatting, and a specific order of copying/pasting things (not all fields are included), I am using a word template with bookmarks that I can feed into VBA. It fills the template well, but I cannot save it as a standard word document before repeating the loop. I get the error 'Object doesn't support this property or method'. Is there a way to overcome it, or a more elegant method I've missed?

Here is the code:

```
Sub Primitive()

Dim objWord As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer


   
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    i = 2 ' First row to process
    'Start of loop
    Do Until ws.Range("B" & i) = ""
         Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
         objWord.Visible = True
     'Change to local path of template file
     

         objWord.Documents.Open "C:path of template file.dotx"
         With objWord.ActiveDocument


              .Bookmarks("FirstBookmark").Range.Text = ws.Range("B" & i).Value & " " & ws.Range("C" & i)
              .Bookmarks("headlineZ").Range.Text = ws.Range("Z1").Value
```

lots of this^ here to arrange the data right in the document

```
           
              NewFileName = "C:\path of where I want the new file" & ws.Range("C" & i).Value & ".docx"
```

This is the line that gives the error 483:

```
    objWord.SaveAs2 Filename:="NewFileName"
    End With
    

    objWord.Close

 Set objWord = Nothing
        

              
        i = i + 1
        Loop
   


End Sub
```

Comment: you have to use the variable without quotation marks: `objWord.SaveAs2 Filename:=NewFileName`

Comment: Do yourself a really big favour and to to Tools | References and set a reference to the Word object model. This will enable you to declare your variables properly instead of declaring them `As Object`. You will then be able to use IntelliSense and the Object Browser to avoid basic mistakes like this, and enable the compiler to flag up mistakes you do make.

Comment: Your repeated use of Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") is awful and is liable to cause your macro to crash. You should also consider automating a mailmerge for this. See, for example, *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips & Tricks** page at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Do not open the template. Instead used Documents.New based on the template. That will automatically give you a .docx file.

Comment: «Instead used Documents.New based on the template» Incorrect! That is done using Documents.Add.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save Word, rather than the document. If you replace this

```
objWord.SaveAs2 Filename:="NewFileName"
```

with this

```
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="NewFileName"
```

it should work better. That said, you should not use ActiveDocument in your macros. Consider replacing

```
objWord.Documents.Open "C:path of template file.dotx"
```

with something like

```
Set TargetDocument = objWord.Documents.Open("C:path of template file.dotx")
```

and replace all `ActiveDocument` with `TargetDocument`.

Comment: Actually `Set TargetDocument = objWord.Documents.Open("C:path of template file.dotx")` should be `Set TargetDocument = objWord.Documents.Add("C:path of template file.dotx")`

Comment: And the use of the variable is wrong: `objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=NewFileName` - the quotation marks have to be removed

Comment: Thank you for all the tips! I implemented the changes, but now I get error 5981 (Application-defined or object-defined error) in the `Set TargetDocument = objWord.Documents.Open("C:path of template file.dotx")` line - what could this be?

Comment: See the first comment on this answer.

Comment: @Lucja - what have you declared `TargetDocument` as? If you’ve been sensible it should be declared as `Dim TargetDocument as Word.Document`. Also see comment below question.